# Should I render everything at the server when I decided to Server-side render?

Tags: php, render, server-side-rendering

I am writing a social website which using Server-side render,

for example , user received the rendered post (HTML) from the server when user created a post,

and append the HTML to the Dom.

--

Now here comes the problem,

when I choose to render everything at the server,

where should  I  render "small things"?

For example,  if I want to generate a photo preview before user upload a photo,

should I create a  tag at the cilent side,

then modify it with JavaScript,

or just request the preview from the server to make y website "fully" server side render?

If I choose the former solution, my website will become hard to manage (Because it's like cilent-side render plus server-side render , which makes me hard to manage the templates)

I perfer the latter solution so I can manage all of my templates at the server,

but it depends on the internet speed, and I cant do anything once the user is offline,

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, would say that your question about where to render "small things" will be responded with a vague answer.  It may seem like an innocuous question, but the answer will be responded by more complex questions! IMO, it is far better to ***ask this question***, than to apply a server-is-better [myopic view](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) to everything.

In general, I view each rendering task through some constraints ***all of which can vary dramatically by user!!***:

```
- origin of content (is the information coming from the client?)
- delivering content (network infrastructure)
- viewing content (client hardware)
```

So, let's try to answer something specific:

> For example, if I want to generate a photo preview before user upload a photo,
>   should I create a tag at the cilent side, then modify it with JavaScript,
>   or just request the preview from the server to make y website "fully" server   side render?

Is the **photo** is coming from the server?

**Yes**: have server render preview

**No**: have the client render it

After reading the first view paragraphs of this [Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-on-twittercom) ariticle, I came to the conclusion that their content would be best rendered on the server.  But further reading, showed that they are *hybridizing* their rendering - some client and some server (complex - just like you said!).

But, that conclusion was made [8 MONTHS](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/09/100_million_active_users_on_twitter/) after they had ***100 million users***! So, be [pragmatic](http://read.humanjavascript.com/ch02-the-big-decision.html) and choose the rendering approach that will enable you to build the application with the least complexity.

Answer (score 0):

After few months I decided to stick with Cilent-side render with Vue.js (and I have to rewrite everything, yay),

The reasons are:

1. Easier to **manage the templates**, **pages**.
2. Great for storing the data for **offline usage** (Because CSR get data only, not the whole page).
3. Separate the render work, so I can **spend less money on my server**.
4. Because everything will **always outputted to the browser**.